# Unable to exit from SSH when executed from TCLSH

Tags: ssh, tcl

I have hard requirement of logging into a terminal via SSH from TCL console and relaunch a tcl script from that terminal. For this I use exec command and it does get executed. The only problem is it doesn't return back to parent code.

I have automated SSH login and it works fine from a bash/csh terminal

But from TCL console, the following happens

Simple example

```
exec ssh hostname pwd
puts "Done"
```

When I execute this code in  TCL, "Done" never gets printed. I just get the output of pwd and that's it.

I have a need of looping SSH into multiple terminals and run TCL jobs on a hardware, but the loop gets stuck after executing the first SSH.

I search the internet for answers and I am not able to find any. Please help.

Comment: You may want to look into using the `expect` utility.

Comment: I am working on hardware tools from xilinx and synopsys which doesn't have expect utility. I only have the tcl console to work from.

Comment: I cannot reproduce, works just fine for me.

Comment: It looks ok. I think we'll need a bigger sample of your code to see what you're doing. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your script is executed by tclsh? As David B mentioned, in Tcl the result of an exec command isn't normally printed unless you do extra work. If the script is actually executed by bash on the other hand, the exec line will replace the shell with the ssh command. That way you will see the output of the pwd command and the puts line is never reached.

Comment: No it is the same code. Now I did a catch to the ssh. if [catch {exec ssh hostname pwd} errmsg] {puts "ssh failed: $errmsg"} and the $errmsg was the output of pwd and then "done" was printed. At least I am able to go ahead in the loop, but unable to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a lot issues going on here. Running ssh with an explicit command (pwd) will usually default to not allocating a tty (ssh -T) and will run the remote shell in non-interactive mode. And the output of a command called from exec is not normally echoed to standard output, so I would not expect you to see the output if you call it from a script. You have to print the result of exec to see the output of the pwd command. Also, different shell startup scripts are run on the remote host depending on which shell the account is set up with and whether it is an interactive or non-interactive shell. It could be .bashrc, .bash_profile, .profile, .cshrc, etc., and if the script behaves differently when it has a tty vs. when it doesn't, that could explain differing behavior between a bash/csh shell and the TCL console.

Without having access to your system, it is hard for me to troubleshoot. I would start with a script like this:

```
set result [exec ssh -T hostname pwd]
puts "result = $result"
puts "Done."
```

Then I would try changing the -T to a -t and trying again. If the output of "pwd" is appearing before the "result =" line, then you can tell that the command is writing the result to a tty instead of standard output, and that's useful information for troubleshooting.

Comment: The only possible wrinkle is that `pwd` is usually a shell builtin, so the `ssh` might be failing (and something is swallowing the error somehow).

Comment: I don't think that pwd being a shell built-in should be a problem. Linux systems also have /usr/bin/pwd and /bin/pwd executables that can be used if the shell built-in is not available (e.g. when calling the command from the exec() system call or when using a login shell that doesn't have that built-in).